# C++ linux socket that sends array of strings(char**) in a single call as concatenated string

Tags: c++, c, arrays, linux, string

I got array of lengthy strings. I have to send them as single concatenated string in a `send (int __fd, const void *__buf, size_t __n, int __flags)` call. I am afraid its a CPU consuming process to construct the single concatenated string(char*). Is there a facility to send array of strings tail to head?

I don't want to call `send` more than once for single meaningful string as long as `recv` fires more than once at the receiving end.

I wonder why there ain't a standardized extendable string structure like linked list in `C/C++` so that readers can jump on to next buffer at the end of a buffer. I wish atleast `std::string` implement this.

Comment: have a look at `writev`

Comment: If you are not using the flags in `send` then you could use `fdopen` to create a `stdio` interface to your socket and then just `fwrite` then one by one to the stream.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I'm using flags in send function. Is it possible with `writev`?

Comment: Why concatenate them? Call `send()` for each string seperatly. TCP/IP sockets are stream oriented, they do not care if the data had been passed in one or several calls to `send()`. Also the receiving side will see no difference.

Comment: @alk some strings can be smaller,only a few bytes, so its again waste of headers in the packet. And I want a single `recv` call to return entire string which is meaningful only when it is whole. I want to avoid burden of concatenating and interpreting at the receiving end.

Comment: @neckTwi, forget about headers and packets.  You don't have much control over how TCP packages your data in packets.  The cost of a small send (to your pgm) is the overhead of system call, which is *nothing* compared to the cost of sending large data over the network.  On the receive side, you have *no control* how the received data arrives.  This is the nature of TCP.  You *will* have to do multiple reads and concatenate the data.

Comment: As others have suggested, just send() each string.  Parse out the individual strings at the recv() end, (presumably by searching for the null terminator).  There is no simple alternative with TCP byte streams.

Comment: Why do you have the need to do this in **one** call to `send()`?

Comment: @Duck k I call `send` for each piece of my string. I hope its the best policy even for `UDP`. Thanq.

Comment: UDP?  recv() is TCP, recvFrom() is UDP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to concatenate all strings in one go. This won't be very CPU consuming since it will happen underneath anyways, but it may or may not consume a lot of memory.

If you are using flags in `send` then you should determine the socket buffer size. Concatenate your strings up to that buffer size and then `send` them one buffer at a time

```
void send_strings(int sockfd, char ** strings, size_t numstrings, int flags) {
    // get the socket write buffer size
    int buflen;
    unsigned int m = sizeof(bufsize);
    if(getsockopt(sockfd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_SNDBUF,(void *)&buflen, &m)) {
        perror("getsockopt"); return; }

    char buffer[buflen];
    int bufsize = 0;

    while (numstrings--) {
        char * string = *(strings++);
        size_t length = strlen(string);

        // if the string would exceed the buffer
        while (length > buflen - bufsize) {
            memcpy(buffer + bufsize, string, buflen - bufsize);

            length -= buflen - bufsize;
            string += buflen - bufsize;

            // send a full buffer
            send(sockfd, buffer, buflen, flags);
            bufsize = 0;
        }
        // copy the string into the buffer
        memcpy(buffer + bufsize, string, length);
        bufsize += length;
    }
    // send the rest
    if (bufsize) {
        send(sockfd, buffer, bufsize, flags);
    }
}
```

Comment: at the receiving end I need to use `recv` more than once for a single string. so I need to add boundaries and interpret them at receiving end. don i hav an easy solution? thanq

Comment: @neckTwi - no, there is no alternative whatsoever to an application-level protocol that can reassemble your strings from a TCP byte-stream at the recv() end.

Comment: @neckTwi You said you just need to send the strings concatenated. If you would have said that you need to marshall them then this is a different story. A simple approach will be to send the null terminator along and use that to differentiate your strings on the receiving end. If you need more complicated marshalling methods then you should put that into your question too.

Comment: @SergeyL. in my question I mentioned `in a single call`

Comment: @neckTwi Is there a reason why? Even if you do one call then in the implementation of `send` your data will still be split into chunks of of socket buffer size.

Comment: Oh, k then, i will use `send` for each string in array. thanku.

Answer (score 0):

http://linux.die.net/man/2/send  states the use of `MSG_MORE` flag. When set, it will initiate transmission only after the `send` call without `MSG_MORE` flag. So call `send` for each data chunk with `MSG_MORE` except for the last data chunk.